# Can {@size} helper be used inside {@math} helper in dust?

Tags: dust.js

Here is the code snippet:

`{@math key="{@size key=result/}" method="subtract" operand="3"/}`

Above code is throwing "**SyntaxError: Expected end tag for eq but it was not found.**".

Is there any other way to achieve above operation in dustjs?

Answer (score 0):

Dust does not allow a helper to be used as the value of a passed parameter.

In general, once you start having to nest helpers, you should ask if you are putting too much logic into your templates instead of into the context-- this is what Dust tries to enforce through relatively-strong restrictions.

You could use a [context helper](http://www.dustjs.com/guides/context-helpers/) to pull this logic out of your template, like this:

```
{#overflow key=results}...and {.} more!{/overflow}
```

Notice how the logic has been removed from the template. Now you're not hard-coding business rules inline.

Add the `overflow` helper to your context:

```
{
  "results": [ ... ],
  "overflow": function(chunk, context, bodies, params) {
    var results = context.resolve(params.key);
    return results.length - 3;
  }
}
```